# Apigility test returns page not found error

Tags: php, api, laminas-api-tools

I'm following the apigility [getting started tutorial](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/getting-started) to setup a simple RPC API. My apigility dashboard is at:

http://localhost:8888/apigility/ui#//module/apiname/1

When I add a simple service called `ping` that returns just a timestamp to acknowledge the request I attempt to test the service by issuing a GET request at:

http://localhost:8888/ping

This returns error 404 although it's the same format as provided in the documentation for the API endpoint. Is there another endpoint where I can test the API before deploying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was a stupid error by myself. I forgot the / before the service route (in the "Route to match" option), which means that the service route should be `/ping` instead of `ping`. After I added the slash it works.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who did that! :)